# Does Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() work like session in .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have built an API application with ASP.NET Core 6. I used `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`, but in production mode it will change every 20 minutes. So does it works like session to change every 20 minutes?

This only works in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your application pool is getting restarted every 20 minutes which is a default behavior set in IIS.  You should not rely on setting the environment variables for data or settings because it will not persist indefinitely. Instead, I would place this code in your Startup class and keep the value in a global class or if you have to use the environment variable for some reason, always add it on startup.

If you're trying to get Session-like behavior then the right way to do this is to read/write the value into a database table that is keyed to the specific user using the user ID or some cookie value.